# Multiple "ManageUsers" with powershell and variable

Tags: azureservicebus, servicebus

I'm trying to run

New-SBNamespace

and use a variable to fill in MULTIPLE users for ManageUsers.

I keep getting "The User Name" (blah blah blah) "is invalid".

Can anyone help with the syntax sugar for this?

```
Clear-Host

#i've tried all of these :(
#no single quotes
[System.String]$myManageUsers = "mydomain\phewson, mydomain\devans"
[System.String]$myManageUsers = "mydomain\phewson,mydomain\devans"
#with single quotes
[System.String]$myManageUsers = "'mydomain\phewson','mydomain\devans'"
[System.String]$myManageUsers = "'mydomain\phewson', 'mydomain\devans'"

#no single quotes
[System.String]$myManageUsers = "phewson@mydomain, devans@mydomain"
[System.String]$myManageUsers = "phewson@mydomain,devans@mydomain"
#with single quotes
[System.String]$myManageUsers = "'phewson@mydomain', 'devans@mydomain'"
[System.String]$myManageUsers = "'phewson@mydomain','devans@mydomain'"

#no quotes
#New-SBNamespace -Name "ServiceBusDefaultNamespace" -AddressingScheme 'Path' -ManageUsers $myManageUsers -Verbose;
#OR with quotes
New-SBNamespace -Name "ServiceBusDefaultNamespace" -AddressingScheme 'Path' -ManageUsers "$myManageUsers" -Verbose;
```

Service Bus 1.1 ON PREMISE

Answer (score 0):

Jimminy Crickets.

There's half a day of my life I'll never get back.

This:

```
[System.String]$myManageUserString = "mydomain\phewson,mydomain\devans"
[System.String[]]$myManageUsersArray = $myManageUserString -split ','
$myManageUsersArray 
New-SBNamespace -Name "ServiceBusDefaultNamespace" -AddressingScheme 'Path' -ManageUsers $myManageUsersArray -Verbose;
```

or this:

```
[System.String[]]$myManageUsersArray = @("mydomain\phewson", "mydomain\devans")
$myManageUsersArray 
New-SBNamespace -Name "ServiceBusDefaultNamespace" -AddressingScheme 'Path' -ManageUsers $myManageUsersArray -Verbose;
```

will work.

The first one I am actually using as I read the values from an xml file.

While I originally knew the argument was an array, the powershell syntax voodoo alluded me.

```
-ManageUsers<String[]>
Specifies user or group names that will be managers of the service namespace.
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248744(v=azure.10).aspx